# What is the difference between v-form and v-card in Vuetify?

Tags: user-interface, vuetify.js

I'm just learning Vuetify and intend to use it in building attractive Vue components in Laravel. (I'm new to Laravel and Vue as well.) I'm trying to build a CRUD and using the Vuetify v-table described at the end of [the v-table page](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) in the docs. Some questions have come to light by imitating this model.

1. The model uses a v-dialog to display the Create and Update pages but elsewhere in the docs, the authors discourage use of v-dialogs for most purposes and only specifically endorse it for things like alerts. Would Create/Update pages be an acceptable use of v-dialog or would it be better to take the user to a separate page entirely, then come back when the Create or Update has completed?
2. The model displays the Create and Update pages on a v-card, even though it appears very much to be a form. Is there any reason to prefer a v-card to a v-form or vice versa in this situation? (I've tried both but v-form had a serious drawback: the form was transparent and I couldn't figure out what made it transparent or how to make it opaque again since none of the props seem to have anything to do with that. I'm not sure if the v-form is inevitably transparent and therefore should never be used in a v-dialog or if there is some simple setting that would make it perfectly usable in a v-dialog.)

Answer (score 0):

to answer your second question first : `v-card` is simply a visual component that makes is easier to create boxes (cards) to display some items with titles and etc. `v-form` on the other hand translate to the `form` tag in html. you can use your `input`s with or without the `form` but using it has it's own benefits but you can leave it out. 
and for the first question : there so many better ways of editing or updating a `v-data-table` than `v-dialog` that you can and should almost always avoid using it for that propose. one of the most common and nicer way of doing it is using `v-alert` with `value` and `transition`  like [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/alerts/#transition) , but if you want to update a row from you `v-data-table`, I suggest using your own templates that has `v-text-field`s instead of the simple `div` inside `td` `v-if` with that's tied to a Boolean on each object that you can toggle with a button. it will be something like this : 
template:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
>
  <template v-slot:item.myEditableCol="{ item  }" v-if="item.beingEdited">
     <v-text-field v-model="item.myEditableCol" />
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item.action="{ item  }">
     <v-icon
       class="mx-1"
       @click.stop="item.beingEdited = !item.beingEdited"
     >
    {{item.beingEdited?'mdi-check':'mdi-circle-edit-outline'}}
    </v-icon>
  </template>                    
</v-data-table>
```

and script :

```
headers: [
      {
        text: "ID",
        align: "start",
        value: "id",
      },
      {
        text: "Title",
        align: "start",
        value: "title",
      },
      {
        text: "Editable",
        align: "start",
        value: "myEditableCol",
      },
      {
        text: "CRUD",
        align: "start",
        value: "actions",
      },
    ],

items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "row1",
        myEditableCol: "someValue1",
        beingEdited: false,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "row2",
        myEditableCol: "someValue2",
        beingEdited: false,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "row3",
        myEditableCol: "someValue3",
        beingEdited: false,
      },

    ],
```

you can basically get super creative with `templates` and `v-slot` in vuetify.
hope it could help.

Comment: It looks like you meant to include a link to an example in your answer but the link doesn't work. Can you fix it please? I'd really like to look at it.

Comment: So what is the benefit of a v-form?